# Is there way to know data is decimal or binary or hexadecimal?

Tags: php, binary, hex, decimal

I need to convert data of which I don't know whether it is

- decimal
- binary
- hexadecimal

to decimal format.

So far, I have tried to use

- `bindec()` to convert binary data to decimal
- `hexdec()` to convert a hexadecimal to decimal

However, I need to determine beforehand whether a number is decimal or hexadecimal.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please show sample data.

Comment: Can you tell if 11 is Eleven, seventeen, or three without any further information?

Comment: Those functions you tried are converting binary and hexadecimal formatted STRINGS to integer. Use `intval()` to automatically detect and convert values. Also, check my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only disctinction between arbitrary bases you can encounter are literals. In PHP, every number are stored as integers or floats.

```
$binary = 0b1100; // stored as 12
$oct    = 014;    // stored as 12
$hex    = 0xC;    // stored as 12
```

However, if your data is a string, you can use regex to determine it's type, than use [`hexdec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php), [`octdec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.octdec.php), [`bindec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) functions to convert them to decimal.

OR, you can use the [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function, which automatically detects the type by the formatting of the string:

```
intval("0b000"); // bin->dec conversion
intval("014");   // oct->dec conversion
intval("0xC");   // hex->dec conversion
intval("12");    // str->dec cast!!
intval("asd");   // str->dec cast!!
```

Watch out with unformatted strings, because intval() will turn everything into a number.